# What is the difference of using arrayName and arrayName[:] in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.x

I just had a problem with Python which I eventually fixed myself. Although I'm still wondering what's the difference of using

```
arrayName
```

and

```
arrayName[:]
```

even if they have the same values. Here's my code where I had the problem:

```
def quickSort(ar, start, end):
    count = 0
    if end - start >= 2:
        p = ar[end-1]
        pos = start
        for i in range(start, end-1):
            if ar[i] < p:
                if i != pos:
                    ar[i], ar[pos] = ar[pos], ar[i]
                pos += 1
                count += 1
        ar[pos], ar[end-1] = ar[end-1], ar[pos]
        count += 1
        count += quickSort(ar, start, pos)
        count += quickSort(ar, pos+1, end)
    return count

def insertion_sort(ar):
    shift = 0
    for i in range(1, len(ar)):
        j = i-1 
        key = ar[i]
        while (j > -1) and (ar[j] > key):
            ar[j+1] = ar[j]
            shift += 1
            j -= 1
        ar[j+1] = key
    return shift

n = int(input())
ar = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(insertion_sort(ar) - quickSort(ar, 0, n))
```

The above will print `-18` but if I change the last line into

```
print(insertion_sort(ar[:]) - quickSort(ar[:], 0, n))
```

it will print `1` which is the correct (the return value of insertion_sort() is 9 and the return value of quickSort() is 8). Why is it returning a wrong value when I didn't use list slicing?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802/3001761

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[:]` notation is a known "syntactic sugar" to **duplicate** the list (it's not an array).

It's a [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) that takes the whole list - effectively duplicating it.

In your code you are not passing the same list when you use the `ar[:]` notation - you're passing an **entirely new list** (with the same members). This way each frame in the `quickSort` recursion has it's **own**, **exclusive** list (`ar`).

This does not happen when you pass the original list as is - which is mutable. Letting two (or way more...) frames modify the same list causes havoc.

Comment: Note: it does duplicate the list (and is particulary useful when modifying a list inside a loop) but it is good to know the syntax `del mylist[:]` does empty the list (and not a copy of the list).

Comment: @bufh I did not see `del` used in this code so this is not in the scope of the question. In this particular case it's frames we worry about - since `quicksort` is a recursive function.

Comment: it was not a critic, just something to let know to the user about the `[:]` syntax.

Comment: @bufh cool, I think there is a question popular question about it as well

Comment: I understand it makes a duplicate but why is it still causing havoc if I make a variable? like

    `ar = list(map(int, input().split()))`
    `copy1 = ar`
    `copy2 = ar`
    `print(insertion_sort(copy1) - quickSort(copy2, 0, n))`